# Multiple Contacts and Memberships Later Merged to One Membership

Tags: civimember, contacts

I have a problem that I'm not entirely certain how to work around. I have two contacts, who have been two separate members for a long period of time. But recently they married and are now sharing one membership (example: Two at same address). How would I record them sharing a single active membership while keeping their past data (as singles we'll say) available for them to review?

Thanks!

Matthew

Comment: You may need to clarify about your Membership Types eg whether you have different Types for individuals v couples

Answer (score -2):

There is an option to merge contacts and seems to be what you are looking for. Search for them in Find Contacts and then select to merge the two.